# passing multi dimentional array as arguments in function

Tags: arrays, r, function, matrix, dataframe

I am trying to do Analytical Hierarchical Process in R.

The Factor Matrix available to me is :-

```
{Matrix <- diag(3)
Matrix[1,2] <- 0.4
Matrix[1,3] <- 0.2
Matrix[2,3] <- 0.5}

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  0.4  0.2
[2,]    0  1.0  0.5
[3,]    0  0.0  1.0
```

To analyse the data, I want to fill the lower triangle of the matrix on the basis of upper triangle. The value at position [i,j] would be reciprocal the value at [j,i].

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Matrix))
    {
    for (j in 1:ncol(Matrix))
      {
    if(i>j)
        {
        Matrix[i,j]=1/Matrix[j,i]
        }
      }
      }
```

The result is as per my expectations :-

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.4  0.2
[2,]  2.5  1.0  0.5
[3,]  5.0  2.0  1.0
```

I have to run a similar dataset several times for each factor in the analysis. So instead of using the code several times, I decided to make a function to handle this.

```
Fill_Matrix <- function(Fact_Matrix){
 for (i in 1:nrow(Fact_Matrix))
 {
  for (j in 1:ncol(Fact_Matrix))
  {
    if(i>j)
    {
      Fact_Matrix[i,j]=1/Fact_Matrix[j,i]
    }
 }
  return (Fact_Matrix)
}}
Fill_Matrix(Matrix)
```

When I am calling this function, I am not able to get the results. It may have something to do with passing array as an argument in function.

Comment: It's a typo: Your `}}` in the final line of the function should have a single `{` and the line above `return` should be `}}`. Note that return ends the function so that your outer loop does not complete a single iteration.

Comment: Rregardless of the typo, you could vectorize your function as follows `indx <- row(Matrix) > col(Matrix) ; Matrix[indx] <- 1/t(Matrix)[indx]` and avoid the double loop.

Comment: can you provide the code that fix this issue?

Comment: Put `return (Fact_Matrix)` *between* the last two curly brackets Or just vectorize the whole thing like I showed above.